# Convert hex number to char string reversed

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.7, hex

I have this variable

```
x = 0x61626364
```

I want the string `"dcba"`, converting the hex number in char, and then reverse the string.

How can I do that in python?

Comment: You have a regular integer; that you used *hex notation* to produce the integer value is neither here nor there, Python doesn't store it as hex notation, so you can safely drop the 'hex' prefix. You want to convert an integer to a character string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
x = 0x61626364
print(x.to_bytes(4, 'little').decode('utf-8'))
```

Explanation:

Using `to_bytes()` we will get the bytecode and to get the string `dcba` use the decode function.

Output:

```
dcba
```

Comment: @Simone De Vita: Is this what you are expecting ?

Comment: @SimoneDeVita: Please confirm the answer so that it will help others

Answer (score 1):

Interpret the integer as bytes in little-endian order, using the [`int.to_bytes()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes):

```
>>> x = 0x61626364
>>> x.to_bytes(4, 'little')
b'dcba'
```

You do need to know the output length for this.

Answer (score 0):

Enjoy!

```
def convert(h):
    result = ''
    while h>0:
        result+=chr(h%256)
        h//=256
    return result


>>> convert(0x61626364)
'dcba'
>>> convert(0x21646c726f57206f6c6c6548)
'Hello World!'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

a = [chr(0xFF&(x>>(8*i))) for i in range(math.ceil(math.log(x, 2)/8))]

b = ""

for i in range(len(a)): b += a[i]

print(b)
```